# JS multiple timers that activates with onChange <select>

Tags: javascript, dom, timer

im trying to have multiple timers on 1 page that activates when a user change the option in a select.
the project has input that saves the value and creates  and then append the value to the options.
im trying to activate the timer onChange of the options.

ive added it to codepen so it will be easy to understand.

i cannot figure out a way to keep the timer for each tr, and restarts with onChange.

https://codepen.io/taldesign/project/editor/ZvxYkV#0

```js
var ids = ["lobby", "tThree"];
var gurds = [];
var counter = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var clockCounter = 0;


function createList() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("uGurd");
    gurds.push(userInput.value);
    userInput.value = "";
}


function userFinish() {
    while (counter < ids.length) {
        var row = document.getElementById(ids[counter]);
        var td = document.createElement("TD");
        row.appendChild(td);
        var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
        td.appendChild(select);

        for (var j = 0; j < gurds.length; j++) {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            option.innerText = gurds[j];
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

setInterval(function () {


    var distance = 3600;
    if (distance > 3600) {
        clearInterval();
        //   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
    if (seconds % 60 == 0 && seconds > 1) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
    }

    var clockPosition = document.getElementsByClassName("clock");

    while (clockCounter < clockPosition.length) {
        clockPosition[clockCounter].innerText = seconds + " : " + minutes + " ";

        clockCounter++;
    }
    clockCounter = 0;

    seconds++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
/**
 * index.scss
 * - Add any styles you want here!
 */

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.HR {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
<body>
  
    <section>
        <container class="HR">
            <div class="flex fullwidth">
                    <input type="text" id="uGurd" placeholder="add name here">
            </div>
            <div class="flex fullwidth">
                    <button type="button" id="clearList" value="add" onclick="createList()">add</button>
            </div>
        </container>
    </section>
  
  
    <section>
        <container class="HR">
            <div class="shuffleDiv">
                <button value="distribute" onclick="userFinish()">send</button>
            </div>
        </container>
    </section>
  
 <section>
        <container class="HR">
            <table id="result">
                <tr>
                    <th>position</th>
                    <th>time</th>
                    <th>worker</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lobby">
                    <td>Lobby</td>
                    <td class="clock"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tThree">
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td class="clock"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </container>
    </section>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want multiple differently timed counters, you will need seconds and minutes to be arrays/vectors as well as  your clockCounter, and run through adding to each of them. You are currently tracking only one time with single variables - as such, every one of your timers will have the same time.

Comment: you mean putting the variables inside a new function scope?

Comment: Look at the notation for your clockCounter variable: `clockPosition[clockCounter]`... I'm not even going to go into the Global vs Passing variable discussion here - since you shouldn't be too worried about memory usage/responsiveness with this code... but also your `seconds` and `minutes`. You would need to run them through a for or while for each `seconds[clockCounter]` and `minutes[clockCounter]`, including expanding the variables (not sure if that memory allocation is manually necessary in Java atm) for each New clock.